# Alphabetical sort order wrong in jQuery Tablesorter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, tablesorter

I'm using the jQuery Tablesorter plugin (http://tablesorter.com/) and it appears to me that their definition of "ascending" vs "descending" is backwards.

Below is the table that is the demo on the Tablesorter site -> http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Demo

[image: Tablesorter demo configuration]

This shows that the column is sorted as "descending" according to Tablesorter, which to my knowledge means it should be sorted Z-A. However, below you can see the result is it being sorted A-Z, which I thought was "ascending".

[image: Resulting sort]

This was brought to my attention because in ActiveRecord, if I sort a collection "ascending" it is A-Z.

Am I crazy here? Or is this an issue with the library?

Comment: This is almost a question for http://english.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @Teemu Good point. I'm also thinking it should be an issue created on the GitHub project. Just wanting to confirm that there isn't something I'm missing here first.

Comment: It is backwards; a problem that has been corrected in my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/).