# Ugrade tablesorter to Mottie fork

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

Have a working instance of tablesorter using V 1.0.3 where everything is working perfectly with selected columns only, a custom image showing and an initial sort (with CSS formatting) on a single column.

The only trouble is with its handling of empty ells and wanted to us the Mottie fork.  Got this working OK as well, however nothing I cold find would allow me to get my images working again.

My CSS portion is:

```
 /* tables sorting
----------------------------------------------------------*/
table.tablesorter {
    margin:10px 0pt 5px;
    font-size: 1.0EM;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
}
table.tablesorter thead tr th, table.tablesorter tfoot tr th {
    font-size:1.0EM;
    padding: 4px;
}
table.tablesorter thead tr .header {
    background-image: url(/Images/bg.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center right;
    cursor: pointer;
}
table.tablesorter tbody td {
    color: #3D3D3D;
    padding: 4px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
table.tablesorter tbody tr.odd td {
    background-color:#F0F0F6;
}
table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortUp {
    background-image: url(/Images/asc.gif);
}
table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortDown {
    background-image: url(/Images/desc.gif);
}
table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortDown, table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortUp {
    background-color: #8dbdd8;
}
```

In my page I currently have (I have reverted back to the original tablesorter, but you can see how there is nothing beyond the normal, except for the change t allow for Empty cells)

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#raceresults").tablesorter({
            sortList: [
                    [0, 0]
                ],
            // pass the headers argument 
            headers: {
                // assign the secound column 
                1: {sorter: false},
                2: {sorter: false},
                3: {sorter: false},
                7: {sorter: false},
                8: {sorter: false},
                9: {sorter: false}
            },
            textExtraction: function (node) {
                if (node.innerHTML.length == 0) {
                    return "999999999";  // or some suitably large number!
                }
                else {
                    return node.innerHTML;
                }
            },

        });
    });
```

and then my HTML has:

```
<table id="raceresults" class="tablesorter">
@if (raceresults.Any())
{
    <thead>
        <tr style="background-color:lightgray">
            <th>Place</th>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th nowrap>Finish Time</th>
            <th>Handicap    </th>
            <th nowrap>Corrected Time   </th>
            <th>Avg Speed   </th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th nowrap>Time Diff</th>
            <th nowrap>Cumm Diff</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
```

.......

and idea why the images wont show?  Does the CSS need to be changed when upgrading the JS file?  As I said, all worked OK in terms of using the *emptyto* bottom.

CHeers

Craig

Comment: PS. forgot to mention I'm using jQuery version 1.10.2

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I've ever seen v1.0.3...

Anyway, if you upgrade from the original tablesorter to my fork, you'll need to include the theme css files, or at least follow the template as some css classes have changed.

The reason for the change was to avoid confusion. The original tablesorter has the icons for ascending & descending sort reversed (see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27747244/145346)). What made it even more confusing was that the class names were labeled "headerSortUp" and "headerSortDown". So to avoid that I renamed the classes to "tablesorter-headerAsc" and "tablesorter-headerDesc"

So, if you want to use the provided css:

```
table.tablesorter thead tr .header {
    background-image: url(/Images/bg.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center right;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* ... */

table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortUp {
    background-image: url(/Images/asc.gif);
}
table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortDown {
    background-image: url(/Images/desc.gif);
}
table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortDown, table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortUp {
    background-color: #8dbdd8;
}
```

you'd need to change some of the default settings ([cssHeader](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#cssheader), [cssAsc](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#cssasc) & [cssDesc](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#cssdesc)):

```
$(function () {
    $('table').tablesorter({
        cssAsc    : 'headerSortUp',
        cssDesc   : 'headerSortDown',
        cssHeader : 'header',
    });
});
```

Actually, those options only add additional class names to the header, so with the above settings on a column with an ascending sort, the class name for that cell will look like this:

```
<th class="tablesorter-header header tablesorter-headerAsc headerSortUp">...</th>
```